# Why are Google search results not working for me? Does it have to do with otnggrneohai?

Tags: virus, virus-removal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

I can't use Google search results right now. The actual searches return results that look valid, but whenever I click on a link, I'm redirected to strange sites. I believe I'm being affected by a virus that has something to do with the string "otnggrneohai."

I was running Windows 7 Home with Microsoft Security Essentials, but Microsoft Security Essentials has been deleted. I did not delete it myself.

Here is the screen shot, I did a search test in google videos:

[image]

Comment: I think it's you falling asleep on your keyboard.  What is the context for this?  Where did you see it?

Comment: when i searching in google returns true results after that when i click on every link first redirect me to strange sites .

Comment: Strange.  When I search on google all I get is Superuser.com and your question.

Comment: yes :( how can find problem ? why microsoft essential security deleted ?

Comment: I think this was a randomly generated session or search ID. Could that be?

Comment: Where do you see `otnggrneohai`? Is it the name of a file that appeared on the desktop? The contents of a popup window? A new user account on the machine? Give us some more context, please!

Comment: @lord Torgamus : please see screen shot i putted.

Comment: This might indeed be a malware attack then. The domain isn't registered though

Comment: how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have malware.

Install and update some AV software and run a full scan. Uninstall and reinstall Firefox. Run Spybot Search & Destroy.

Comment: Although this is a useful answer, we have a [community wiki](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware) to describe how to perform a disinfection. Please feel free to add your own method or edit the answers already given to suit your method. Please refer the OP of questions about disinfection to this community wiki and close to vote as a duplicate if you can and if it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that unless you have a compelling reason not to you should **BACK UP YOUR DATA**, reformat your hard drive (or buy a new one) and then reinstall Windows and all your applications.  If antivirus vendors don't know about whatever malware this is, you'll have a very hard time removing it without the reinstall.

The alternative would be to call Microsoft support (since you're using their antivirus/antimalware protection) and try to get them to help you diagnose and fix the problem.  Since you aren't a major corporate customer or MVP, don't hold your breath while waiting for them to get back to you.

Comment: Buy a new hard drive? Because of a virus? No.

Comment: New hard drives cost less than, say, two tanks of gas for a mid-size car these days.  No, I wouldn't tend to do it, but I'm comfortable with low-level formatting.

Comment: Right, but the existing hard drive costs as much as _nothing_, becuase he already has it. If somebody isn't comfortable with reformatting their drive, they probably won't be any more comfortable with replacing it.